# StackExchange.Redis simple C# Example

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am looking for a very simple starter C# application for using StackExchange.Redis
I have search over the web and found [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/tree/master/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis)

But this doesn't seems like a quick startup example.

I have setup redis on windows using 
[StackExchange.Redis exe](https://github.com/downloads/rgl/redis/redis-2.4.6-setup-64-bit.exe)

Can anyone help me locate a simple C# application connecting with redis server and setting and getting some keys.

Comment: Are you looking to use caching or state server?

Comment: Have you seen the [readme](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/README.md)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can find C# examples in the [readme](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Basics) file.

```
using StackExchange.Redis;
...

ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
// ^^^ store and re-use this!!!

IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
string value = "abcdefg";
db.StringSet("mykey", value);
...
string value = db.StringGet("mykey");
Console.WriteLine(value); // writes: "abcdefg"
```

Comment: I also recommend you the [CachingFramework.Redis](https://github.com/thepirat000/CachingFramework.Redis) library that is built on top of SE.Redis and provides extra functionality like tagging mechanism, pluggable serialization and lot more.

Comment: This is a bad example - the redis object is long-lived and example doesn't capture that

Comment: @Abr you're right, so I've edited and added a comment to the code sample

Answer (score 8):

See the following code from their [github sample](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/StackExchange.Redis.Tests/BasicOps.cs):

```
 using (var muxer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost,resolvedns=1"))
        {
            muxer.PreserveAsyncOrder = preserveOrder;
            RedisKey key = "MBOA";
            var conn = muxer.GetDatabase();
            muxer.Wait(conn.PingAsync());

            Action<Task> nonTrivial = delegate
            {
                Thread.SpinWait(5);
            };
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i <= AsyncOpsQty; i++)
            {
                var t = conn.StringSetAsync(key, i);
                if (withContinuation) t.ContinueWith(nonTrivial);
            }
            int val = (int)muxer.Wait(conn.StringGetAsync(key));
            watch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("After {0}: {1}", AsyncOpsQty, val);
            Console.WriteLine("({3}, {4})\r\n{2}: Time for {0} ops: {1}ms; ops/s: {5}", AsyncOpsQty, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, Me(),
                withContinuation ? "with continuation" : "no continuation", preserveOrder ? "preserve order" : "any order",
                AsyncOpsQty / watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        }
```

Comment: Your link is 404 now... what is AsyncOpsQty?

Comment: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/tests/StackExchange.Redis.Tests/MassiveOps.cs

Comment: This is a bad example because the Connection Multiplexer object is LONG LIVED!  It should not be used in this way

Comment: Agreed. This is example was around 2015 when i have nearly first used it. Even the provided sample doesn't exists from which i have referred it .You are free to post a good example in the answer :)

Comment: You also forgot to increase minimum worker thread pool count.

Comment: @TimLovell-Smith this post is at the time of .net framework related implenetation. I faced minimum thread pool related problem only in .net core type of appliction which i handled there separately

Answer (score 3):

- //-- Install-Package StackExchange.Redis -Version 1.2.6
- In this simple example: set new string key/value to redis with expiry time, get redis string value by key from redis:
- Code:

  ```
  public string GetRedisValue()
  {
      var cachedKey = "key";
      string value;

      using (var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost:6379"))
      {
          IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();

          if (!db.KeyExists(cachedKey))
          {
              value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
              //set new value
              db.StringSet(cachedKey, value, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(18));
          }
          else
          {
              //get cached value
              value = db.StringGet(cachedKey);
          }
      }

      return value;
  }
  ```