# How to connect to redis cache via redis URL using StackExchange.Redis?

Tags: c#, caching, redis, stackexchange.redis

Currently, I am using **ServiceStack.Redis** to connect to Redis Cache server. The redis cache URL structure is like: *`redis://f:UIOPabcdXYZ@ip-172-31-81-144.manager.{domain}.io:33004`*

Below is a sample code to connect to Redis Cache using *ServiceStack.Redis*

```
var redisClientManagerPool = new RedisManagerPool(ConfigManager.RedisCacheUrl);

using (var client = redisClientManagerPool.GetClient())
{
    //SetClientData(key, client, data);
}
```

But the free version has certain restrictions and once it reaches the limit, it gives error like

> The free-quota limit on '6000 Redis requests per hour' has been
>   reached. Please see https://servicestack.net to upgrade to a
>   commercial license or visit https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3 to
>   revert back to the free ServiceStack v3

I want to use `StackExchange.Redis` to connect to redis cache. But I didn't get any code reference how to use the redis URL from https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Basics .

I am looking for any code reference to use redis cache URL like *`redis://f:UIOPabcdXYZ@ip-172-31-81-144.manager.domain.io:33004`* to connect to redis cache server by using `StackExchange.Redis` nuget. Any help is appreciated.

**Note:** The current used library is .NET Standard 2.0 version of ServiceStack.Redis. The nuget name is `ServiceStack.Redis.Core` version 5.7.0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [StackExchange.Redis simple C# Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888513/stackexchange-redis-simple-c-sharp-example)

Comment: No, I already tried that but it didn't work with the redis URL format. I didn't find any configuration related to redis:// URL structure in https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration

Comment: have you tried servicestack-redis v 3.0.71. https://ppolyzos.com/2015/10/08/issues-when-downgrading-to-servicestack-redis-v3/

Comment: The exact library is .NET Standard 2.0 version of ServiceStack.Redis. The nuget name is `ServiceStack.Redis.Core` version 5.7.0. Is there any equivalent free version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The StackExchange.Redis worked for `redis://f:UIOPabcdXYZ@ip-172-31-81-144.manager.{domain}.io:33004` URL format. Below is the code reference:

```
var url = "redis://f:UIOPabcdXYZ@ip-172-31-81-144.manager.{domain}.io:33004";
var urlParts = url.Split("@ip-");
var password = urlParts[0].Split("redis://f:")[1].Trim();
var host = "ip-" + urlParts[1].Split(":")[0].Trim();
var port = int.Parse(urlParts[1].Split(":")[1].Trim());
var redisConfigurationOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
{
    AllowAdmin = false,
    Ssl = false,
    Password = password,
    EndPoints = {
                    {  host, port }
                }
};

var conn = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConfigurationOptions);
var client = conn.GetDatabase();
client.StringSet(cacheKey, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));

//To retrieve data
if (client.KeyExists(cacheKey))
{    
   var outputString = client.StringGet(cacheKey).ToString();    
}
else
{
  //cacheKey doesn't exists
}
```